# Nodejs api gives the same result if hit multiple apis in a loop

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

Created APIS in the backend(nodejs)

Now hitting that API from frontend or from another server backend

When I hit the requests in the loop, it gives the result of the previous request.

Suppose we're fetching user data by id and along with its user categories

Following are the user ids 1,2 and 3

From the frontend or backend, I have an array that I need to hit to fetch the user detail

In frontend arr or another backend= [1,2,3]
Consider another backend

```
const async = require('async');
const axios = require('axios');
let userIds = [1,2,3]

async.each(userIds , function (item, next) {
          console.log("item which is id", item);              
          ongoingReq(item, next);
        }, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
            return;
          }    
        });

function ongoingReq(item, next) {
  // Configure the request 
  let headers = {
  }
  let url = `url${item}/data`;

  axios.get(url, {headers})
  .then(d=>{  
    console.log(d.data.id, item); //item is 1 or 2 or 3 but d.data.id data always giving the first result which processed by the backend
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log("d err", item, err);
  })
}
```

Then cross-checked in the backend it gives the same result. **So how would even that possible `NodeJs API` gives the result of the other API data.**

Don't know why that happened and when I hit api one by one or delay between the APIs then the backend processes data correctly. But whenever the request is sent in a loop/ so many requests at the same time it gives the result of another user irrespective of another user.

Any suggestions for this?

Problem from Nodejs server coming not in the front end or backend server

Answer (score 0):

I think it could have to do with the way javascript handles loop :

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}

//---> Output  5,5,5,5,5
```

Maybe try :

```
let data = await Promise.all(
  userIds.map(userId =>
    axios.get(`url${userId}/data`, {headers})
  )
)
```

Comment: I m not talking about the i value, I m talking about the response of the API which some same and it due to the backend from where API is writtern

Comment: If the problem comes from Nodejs api could you share api's code please ? (What is next ? Could the problem come from this ? )

Comment: this api works fine if I hit after some time or manually hit API from postman or swagger but when I hit simultaneously from API, it gives that old data. Btw how is that even possible

Comment: If your api is ok it is not. Are you sure that you run different queries ? Could you ```console.log(url)``` ?

Comment: Yes I have checked that it coming different url

Comment: Ok, I've no idea what is happening here, if the problem comes from api maybe you should share the code ?